# Grouping subarrays in array by the same items Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array

```
arr = [["cat", "15"], ["dog", "17"], ["cat", "20"], ["cat", "356"], ["dog", "89"], ["bird", "65"], ["dog", "336"], ["bird", "545"]]
```

I want to group subarrays by the same first item, I just need to get something like that:

```
arr = [["cat", "15", "20", "356"], ["dog", "17", "89", "336"], ["bird", "65","545"]]
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: start with `group_by`

Comment: _"**group** subarrays **by** the same **first** item"_ → `group_by(&:first)` should get you started

Comment: You should consider converting to a hash to give your values for each animal i.e. `{"cat"=>["15", "20", "356"], "dog"=>["17", "89", "336"], "bird"=>["65", "545"]}`.  One way to get this: `arr.group_by(&:first).transform_values {|v| v.map(&:last)}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next time it would be great if you will add some steps you was tried to do to get what you want, here is a fast solution:

```
> arr.group_by(&:shift).map(&:flatten)
#=> [["cat", "15", "20", "356"], ["dog", "17", "89", "336"], ["bird", "65", "545"]]
```

But, this will mutate original `arr`

@Md.FarhanMemon have good solution without mutate

Comment: Okay worth adding a caveat that this mutates the original array.

Comment: yeah, we need deep dup here. And this one doesn't do anything :)

Comment: but don't implement it. Leave him _something_ to do :)

Comment: Ok, this is the imperative approach, anyone with a functional one?

Comment: The `#uniq` assumes there are no duplicates in the first place. (:

Answer (score 2):

Alternate solution, doesn't change original object, doesn't need dup..

```
arr.group_by(&:first).map{ |k, v| [k] + v.map { |e| e[1] } }
#=> [["cat", "15", "20", "356"], ["dog", "17", "89", "336"], ["bird", "65", "545"]]
```

OR

```
arr.group_by(&:first).map{ |k, v| [k] + v.map(&:last) }
#=> [["cat", "15", "20", "356"], ["dog", "17", "89", "336"], ["bird", "65", "545"]]
```

Comment: or `[k] + v.map(&:last)` or `v.map(&:last).unshift(k)`

Comment: I edited your answer because I assumed that `|` was a typo, but maybe it was `Array#|`?

Comment: @Stefan it wasn't a typo :) and yes there can be multiple variations to map second part.. `v.map(&:last)` looks shorter though

Comment: `|` could inadvertently discard duplicates: `['cat'] | ['1', '1', '1'] #=> ["cat", "1"]`

Comment: ohh yes, I should've mentioned that in the answer..anyway, thanx

Answer (score 2):

The other answers already provide perfectly fine solutions. I'm posting this one to show an application for the (little known?) [`assoc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-assoc) method. It scans the array for a subarray with the given first element, almost as if the array was a hash. This can be used to populate a results `array`:

```
result = []
arr.each do |name, value|
  group = result.assoc(name)
  if group
    group << value
  else
    result << [name, value]
  end
end

result
#=> [["cat", "15", "20", "356"], ["dog", "17", "89", "336"], ["bird", "65", "545"]]
```

The code can be further shorted to:

```
arr.each_with_object([]) do |(name, value), result|
  group = result.assoc(name)
  group ? group << value : result << [name, value]
end
#=> [["cat", "15", "20", "356"], ["dog", "17", "89", "336"], ["bird", "65", "545"]]
```

`assoc` can also be used to easily retrieve the values for a specific "key" from the `result` array:

```
name, *values = result.assoc('cat')
name   #=> "cat"
values #=> ["15", "20", "356"]
```

Comment: Neat. I think this is the most efficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is by adding all values in hash:

```
animals = arr.each_with_object(Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = []}) do |(animal_name, value), obj|
  obj[animal_name] << value
end
#=> {"cat"=>["15", "20", "356"], "dog"=>["17", "89", "336"], "bird"=>["65", "545"]}
```

And then convert it to expected output:

```
animals.map(&:flatten)
#=> [["cat", "15", "20", "356"], ["dog", "17", "89", "336"], ["bird", "65", "545"]]
```